# Pure CSS for the border between two text areas

Tags: css

I got the design that between two menu options there is 2px border. Please see the image:

[image]

The tricky thing is that the border is shorter than the height of the menu texts. **The menu texts have to be in two lines, the exact way they are shown. I have more items like this with different width of text.** I would like to have a pure CSS solution for it, but cannot figure out the right way. I tried different ways and this is what I got closest:

```
    <div style="height: 15px; display:inline-block; border-left: 2px solid red; padding:0 15px;">First<br/>Item</div>
    <div style="height: 15px; display:inline-block; border-left: 2px solid red; padding:0 15px;">Second<br/>Item</div>
```

See the picture for the above work:

[image]

The problem is that the border is not in the middle vertically. How can I make the border stay in the middle vertically?

Or any other CSS way to achieve what is shown in the design?

Comment: remove that `<br>` in there. it is messing up the styling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example with a `:before` pseudo element:
https://jsfiddle.net/qfadxsyd/7/

```
.box:before {
  position:absolute;
  content:'';
  height:80%;
  right:-1px;
  width:2px;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:auto;
  background:red;
 }
```

And some funny games in order to hide the last border. Good luck!

*Note: I have removed whitespace between the divs so as to remove the ghost margins between `inline-block;` elements:*

```
<div class="box box">box<br/>Item</div><div class="box box">box<br/>Item</div><div class="box box">box<br/>Item</div><div class="box box">box<br/>Item</div><div class="box box">box<br/>Item</div><div class="box box">box<br/>Item</div><div class="box box">box<br/>Item</div><div class="box box">box<br/>Item</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me!! I tried your approach and made modifications to it. The vertical bar is not in the middle any more. See this: https://jsfiddle.net/qfadxsyd/2/

Comment: No problem. Some of the answers to your question deserve an upvote. Also, I still see the vertical bars in the middle in your updated JSFiddle?

Comment: Upvoted each answer. Thanks for reminding me of it. I usually upvote a lot:-). See this link of what I mean regarding your answer: https://jsfiddle.net/qfadxsyd/4/

Comment: Check this out, demonstrating it is indeed in the middle: https://jsfiddle.net/qfadxsyd/6/ what is NOT in the middle is your text, you should try using a solution better than <br/>

Comment: If you want to make sure the border fits the text then just remove the `height ` attribute like I did or set it to `auto`.

Comment: Fausto, thanks for your updated solution. I believe it should work in my case. I will fully test it out against the actual design  tomorrow and select yours as the answer. Again, thanks for your help. Best.

Comment: Good luck. Feel free to comment again if the code fails somehow.

Comment: Fausto, your solution works. would it be helpful to post your html and css in the answer? Also, I dont see CSS classes "first" or "second" play any role. It seems that there can be only one CSS class: box. Besides, If you can put each <div class="box">...</box> in each line, it would be even better. Regards.

Comment: You're right! adding that to the answer. Also, we should clean up this mess.

Comment: Also, putting all the box divs in one line has the purpose of avoiding ghost margins between the inline-block elements, as I mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [`:before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) pseudo element

```css
body, html, ul {
  margin: 0;  
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

li:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border-left: 2px solid red;
  height: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<ul class="content">
  <li>First <br> Item</li>
  <li>Second <br> Item</li>
  <li>Lorem <br> ipsum  dolor</li>
  <li>lessons & <br> resources</li>
  <li>Lorem <br> ipsum <br> dolor</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nenad, I just updated my question. The menu texts have to be in two lines, exact way they are shown in the design.

Comment: In my answer text is also in two lines

Comment: div  {width: 50px;} makes the padding around text not equal. If you remove it, the text becomes one line.  See this: https://jsfiddle.net/2u6efuv3/1/

Comment: @curious1 sorry for late response, i updated my answer so try it now. You can just remove width and set `br` in html and it will still work

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you.

```css
.items{
  height: 15px; 
  display:inline-block; 
  border-left: 2px solid #777; 
  padding:0 15px;
  padding-bottom:20px;
  color:#777;
  margin-top:10px;
}

#no-border{
  border:none;
  }
```

```html
<div id="no-border" class="items">First<br/>Item</div>
    <div class="items">Second<br/>Item</div>
```

Comment: Np, but can you explain in more detail? I'm happy to learn more.

Comment: Hi, I tested your code in jsfiddle. It seem the vertical bar is not shorter than the text area. Here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/q09agm0n/

Comment: Theoretically you should only have 1 id per Dom tree, or in other word 1 id per page, so at the moment when you are applying `#no-border`. You are saying that the dom element is unique in your page and will not be reusable. so, you are saying that #no-border will not be use again. In other word if you want to assign to a new element the same property of `border:0` you will have to rewrite another definition in you CSS file instead of reusing the class. so one option is to define 
`.no-border {   border:0; }`

and in the html `<div class="item no-border">`